# For loop lasts infinitely javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have a problem in my code:

```
var row = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
var column = ["1","2","3","4","5"];

var arrayLength = row.length;
var arrayLength2 = column.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    for (var e = 0; e < arrayLength2; e++) {
        var samples = document.querySelectorAll('[data-row-id="'+row[i]+'"][data-column-id="'+column[e]+'"]');

        for(var i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {
            var sample = samples[i];

            sample.setAttribute('data-sample-id', row);
            console.log("Colore cambiato");
        }
    }
}
```

When i run it, the cycle lasts infinitely and the console.log is called up a lots of times

Where is the error? Thanks!

Comment: Gotta love those dynamic arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your inner-most loop uses the same `i` looping variable as your outer most loop and it's constantly changing `i` so that the outer loop never finishes.

Change the variable on your inner loop to a different identifier that you aren't already using in the same scope.

Answer (score 1):

Youre using same loop `i` twice nested so it runs infinitely coz it always resets `i` in inner loop

use something else instead like `k`

```
   for(var k = 0; k < samples.length; k++) {
        var sample = samples[k];

        sample.setAttribute('data-sample-id', row);
        console.log("Colore cambiato");
    }
```